# How to sort specific column when using GROUPING SETS in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

If I remember correctly, in SQL Server, it is not recommended to use "ORDER BY" when there's already a GROUP BY GROUPING SETS.

I have two columns: [UPC#] & [Description]
both are varchar.

My grouping sets is like this:

```
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS 
(
    ([UPC],[Description])
    ,()     
)
```

I don't have 'ORDER BY' but it's automatically sorting the Description column.

If I added a 3rd column, sum(Qty), then it doesn't sort by Description anymore.
But if I added

```
ORDER BY [Description]
```

The grand total of sum(Qty) will be at the first row instead of the last.

Is there a way to sort the Description column and still let the grand total of sum(Qty) be at the last row instead?

Thanks.

***Edit 1****
This is my code as requested:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN [UPC] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [UPC]
    END AS [UPC]

    ,   CASE WHEN [Description] IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE [Description] 
        END AS [Description]

    ,CONVERT(int,ROUND(SUM([QtySold]),0)) AS [Total Count]

FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        [UPC]
        ,[Description]
        , sum([QtySold]) as [QtySold]
    FROM [JS_Data].[dbo].[View_ItemMovement_AllItems_withoutZero]
    WHERE 
        ([Description] LIKE '%drink%') 
        AND (SaleDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-15')
        AND ( (StoreNumber = '1') OR (StoreNumber = '2') OR (StoreNumber = '3') OR (StoreNumber = '4') OR (StoreNumber = '6') OR (StoreNumber = '7') OR (StoreNumber = '8') )
    GROUP BY 
            [UPC]
            ,[Description]
) a

GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS 
    (
        (
            [UPC]
            ,[Description]
        )
        ,()     
    )

ORDER BY [Description]
```

[image]

So how do I move the grand total 1396 to the last row?

Comment: Please be precise on your example, your table has just 2 columns `UPC` and `Description`, how could you add the `sum(Qty)` (which should involve some column called `Qty`)

Comment: that's why i said "IF I added a 3rd column."

Comment: so what you aggregate here with the grouping sets clause? In other words, you should show some specific query and we just need to modify the `Order By` part.

Comment: just added my code and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should know about the `grouping()` function, it will return `1` if the passed-in column joined in some aggregate grouping **and** the current value is `NULL`. Of course we need to do some trick with the `Order By` clause, something like this:

```
--....
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS 
(
    (
        [UPC]
        ,[Description]
    )
    ,()     
)
ORDER BY 
      CASE WHEN
           -- this ensures the total row is always put at the end
           GROUPING([UPC]) = 1 AND GROUPING([Description]) = 1 THEN '1'
           ELSE '0' + [Description]
      END
```

I guess in this case you can even check for `NULL` instead of using `GROUPING`, but it's not safe (in case there is some actual NULL value such as in the Description).

Comment: Thanks. It works.

I got another suggestion like this:
ORDER BY CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID(([UPC]),([Description]))= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,[Description]

Could you briefly explain the difference? I don't quite understand the 3, 1, 0 part.
Thanks.

Comment: @user3486647 thanks for the info, actually I've just used `GROUPING` before but looks like `GROUPING_ID` is new and actually helpful. The `3` here means the binary expression `11`, that means the `UPC` and `Description` both join in the grouping sets, if just the `Description`, the binary expression will be `01` and the decimal value is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is aging a bit, but just came across an example in an MCSA study guide today and I thought I would share. I've tested this and it works with a nearly identical grouping set arrangement.

```
...
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
(
    ([UPC],[Description])
    ,()     
)
ORDER BY GROUPING(UPC);
```